# Php file access permission

Tags: php, apache, permissions, permission-denied

How can I run a PHP file in Apache as the root user? I tried accessing `http://localhost/test.php` but it tells me

> You don't have permission to access /test.php on this server.

I have tried to add the root user to Apache group like:

- `gpasswd -a root apache`
- `chgrp apache /var/www/html`
- `chmpde g+w /var/www/html`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to access one script with another script, or just access it in your browser?

Comment: Have you configured apache httpd.config file ?

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when there are not sufficient permissions to access the file.

Open a terminal, and type this command:

```
chmod 644 /var/www/html/test.php
```

You do not need to set permissions as `root`.